# ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range. - Fails to add strings to data structures

Tags: c#, argumentexception

I have a function to create a graph and add some values to a few other data structures using a `StreamReader` to read in lines from a .txt file.

```
public static DirectedGraph<string, bool> GetGraph(string fn)
{
    DirectedGraph<string, bool> dg = new DirectedGraph<string, bool>();
    ITrie trie = null;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fn))
        {
            string l;
            while((l = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                dg.AddNode(l);
                trie.Add(l);
                list.Add(l);
                GetEdges(list, trie, dg);
            }

            return dg;
        }

    } catch
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

I expect the `StreamReader` to add the read values to a list, `trie` and nodes in a graph. `GetEdges()` is a function that gets strings from the given list and adds edges to the graph data structure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why are you throwing an `ArgumentException` if *anything* goes wrong? I'd strongly suggest removing the try/catch block - it'll make it a lot easier to work out what's wrong if you let the original exception propagate.

Comment: Note that while `trie` is `null`, `trie.Add(l)` will throw `NullReferenceException`, aside from anything else.

Comment: You never set `trie` to anything...

Comment: Yup, you're getting a `NullReferenceException`, but because of how you wrote your exception handler, you'd never know it.  Why are you catching exceptions just to throw an unrelated, blank, exception?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Putting any potentially questionable code practices aside, congratulations on having a well-formatted, well-written question! We love to see things like that.

Answer (score 0):

As @JonSkeet and @RufusL have pointed out, `trie` is instantiated as `null`, and as it is never set to anything, it is **still** `null` when `trie.Add(l);` is called. This throws a `NullReferenceException`, but because of the `try/catch` block, that exception is caught, its data is ignored, and instead an `ArgumentException` with default values is thrown in its place. I would highly recommend having some way of throwing or getting data from the original exception for debugging purposes.